# Strange behavior in registerStoredProcedureParameter in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

First of all, I am using MySql and EclipseLink.

I am calling a stored procedure through JPA, I am attempting to make all the configuration in a non-specific method, I mean, I want to make a general method in order to reuse it in any time I need call a (any) procedure.

Currently doing some test I have two versions of the method.

In the first one I just pass to the method the name of the procedure and I configure (and put the data) into the method.

To call it I just do:

```
myClass.callProcedure("insert_test");
```

The method is:

```
public void callProcedure(String nameProcedure){

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(nameProcedure);

    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("nombre", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("apellido", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("telefono", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    storedProcedure.setParameter("nombre", "John");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("apellido", "Doe");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("telefono", 54321);

    storedProcedure.execute();
}
```

The second one is more general and it looks like this:

```
public void callProcedure(String nameProcedure, Map paramsConfig, Map paramsValue){

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(nameProcedure);

    Iterator config = paramsConfig.entrySet().iterator();

    while(config.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry conf = (Map.Entry)config.next();
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(conf.getKey().toString(), (Class) conf.getValue(), ParameterMode.IN);           
    }

    Iterator params = paramsValue.entrySet().iterator();
    while(params.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry par = (Map.Entry)params.next();
        storedProcedure.setParameter(par.getKey().toString(), par.getValue());
    }

    storedProcedure.execute();
}
```

To call this last one I do:

```
public void callProcedure(){

    Map<String, Class> conf = new HashMap<String, Class>();
    conf.put("nombre", String.class);
    conf.put("apellido", String.class);
    conf.put("telefono", Integer.class);

    Map params = new HashMap();
    params.put("nombre", "Carlos");
    params.put("apellido", "Herrera");
    params.put("telefono", 123456789);

    myClass.callProcedure("insert_test", conf, params);
}
```

However, the problem is that in the second one the data is stored in the wrong column in the database as you can see in the image below:

[image: Data result]

Doing some other tests I could verify that the problem is with the `map` that made the configuration... I mean, If I combine the two methods and do this:

```
public void callProcedure(String nameProcedure, Map paramsValue){

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(nameProcedure);

    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("nombre", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("apellido", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("telefono", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    Iterator params = paramsValue.entrySet().iterator();

    while(params.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry par = (Map.Entry)params.next();
        storedProcedure.setParameter(par.getKey().toString(), par.getValue());
    }

    storedProcedure.execute();
}
```

It works fine, but if I do:

```
public void callProcedure(String nameProcedure, Map paramsConfig, Map paramsValue){

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(nameProcedure);

    Iterator config = paramsConfig.entrySet().iterator();

    while(config.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry conf = (Map.Entry)config.next();
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter(conf.getKey().toString(), (Class) conf.getValue(), ParameterMode.IN);           
    }

    storedProcedure.setParameter("nombre", "John");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("apellido", "Doe");
    storedProcedure.setParameter("telefono", 54321);

    storedProcedure.execute();
}
```

Then the information is stored incorrectly.

**My question is:** why is happening this or how I can fix it if we have in consideration that:

**First**, It is suppose that does not matter the order in the `registerStoredProcedureParameter` nor in `storedProcedure.setParameter` because in both the name of the parameter is use to configurate and asign the values, **and Second**, When I configure and pass the parameters directly (as I show you in the first method) it actually works?.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Having the same problem. From what I observe, the parametres are not passed by name, but simply sequentially (and the order is changed). I have trouble believing this is how this was intended to work.